# How to filter commonly used words from document text? (Hash Maps)

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

Thank you for reading. I currently have a school project I am really stuck on. The purpose is to retrieve document text from the web and then store each word into a map object while omitting commonly used words like "which, about, during, after," etc.

Essentially it comes down to this:

//List of words to ignore

```
    Set<String> ignore = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]{
  "after", "which", "later", "other", "during", "their", "about"}));
```

//Will iterate through the document text (content) for words that adhere 
to the word_pattern (lets say word will have 5 letters or more for simplicity)

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile(word_pattern).matcher(content);
while (match.find()) {
   String word = match.group().toLowerCase();
```

So now in this while loop I wish to skip any word in the ignore set and otherwise add it to a map object... but I can not seem to get it right and nothing seems to click for me. I can easily just add all the words to a map object and take some point deductions but I would like to be able to get this right for my sanity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ignore words list is a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) which offer the [`contains`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method so you 
can simply add this condition in your loop :

```
if(!ignore.contains(word))
{
    //addToList
}
```

Comment: I think you mean `if(!ignore.contains(word))`?

Comment: From that documentation, you can see the contains function which "Returns true if this set contains the specified element."

Comment: I appreciate the quick responses and of course such an easy solution. In my head I had the if statement backwards or trying to do an equals method. Thank you thank you.

Comment: @Wexylwoxyl You're welcome. Thanks to Anubian and Justin too for fixing my answer.

Comment: A+ for effort @Jean-FrançoisSavard!